# How can I highlight text in Mitmproxy?

Tags: python, proxy, mitmproxy, penetration-tools

Is there a way for searching plain text in Mitmproxy views (`Flow list`, `Flow view`, `Keybindings`, `Commands`)? I can filter the flows by pressing `f` but I'm really missing feature like `/` in Vim. It would be faster to navigate to the right flow and in the meanwhile preserve the current view_filter.

It's not documented but in the `Flow view -> Response` there is a `search (/)` functionality which unfortunately highlights the whole matching line making it difficult to read.

Currently, I use the search feature of tmux, but it can find only on the current viewport.

Comment: Instead of starting `mitmproxy` you can start `mitmweb`that opens up a port that provides a web based GUI. Using your favorite web browser you can then easily search and highlight your find string.

Comment: thanks for the comment. In my case, I'm using MITM remotely through the terminal where there is no chance to use GUI. :|

Comment: A web GUI is never shown in the terminal. It just opens up a TCP port where you connect using a web-browser. Via SSH you can use SSH port-forwarding to forward this port to your local machine.